# Javascript: access to class method from another method of the same class

Tags: javascript, oop

Newbie to classes in javascript and can't solve this problem. Actually, anothermethod can return a callback to constructor and then I can can call onemethod from there, but maybe there's an easier way?

```
function sample() {} //constructor

sample.prototype = {
    onemethod: function () {},
    anothermethod: function () {
        onemethod(); //Doesn't work
        this.onemethod(); //Still the same
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.onemethod()` works. Also, when asking questions please create a self contained full example including how you create and call the method.

Comment: `this.onemethod()` is working `alert/console.log` inside the method `onemethod`

Comment: Research javascript prototyping

Comment: call is simple: var s = new sample();

Comment: You are correct that you need to specify the 'this' keyword to access the object scope.  Your first call to onemethod() is failing as a undefined reference.  This stops the execution of the script so your correct reference this.onemethod() is not being called.  Here's an example of making this self-contained per Ben's suggestion:  http://jsfiddle.net/GMg8Y/

Comment: Yes, it works, but shouldn't be called from outside. another method is a callback assigned to event in constructor.

Comment: @BlackenedSun please add _full_ code illustrating your issue and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For it to work, you need to use it correctly. A constructor needs to be call via [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2Fnew).

```
var s = new sample();
s.anothermethod();
// identical to
sample.anothermethod.apply(s);
```

This way, `this` will represent `s` (and this the outer context, usually `window`).